# Need an Interpreted Language with Bayes on Win32 for mini-project

Tags: bayesian, interpreted-language

I used to use Python with Reverend Thomas so I could do things like:

"Hola, coma estas", Spanish
"Hi, How are you?", English
"Muy gracias", Spanish

But I can't find the Reverend package anymore after upgrading my machine.

I need to do very simple Bayes classification like the above with "text", class and just want it to be fast and simple for me to get up and running.

I am currently running Python 3.2 but will use ANY language you can give me that I can install that is interpreted and that I can use Bayes to do the above right away. I looked at a Python-Redis-Bayes module but that would error on the installation.

Please give me the name of an interpreted language that I can install on a Windows machine that has a simple to install (no multi-dependencies, no having to install a package manager after installing the language to then get the Bayes package) Bayes package that will very quickly allow me to use it to classify inputs (text, numbers, strings) into classes.

Optionally, if it can inherently process CVS files that would great.

Second Optionally, if it could then, given a class, show the main components of it or even DIFF the classes that would be awesome but is a nice to have a not a necessity.

Thank you!